# How to update this component from a button

Tags: reactjs

Help me, How to update the `<DatePicker/>` component from the `<Button/>`. This is currently updated directly on onchange.

Example   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYQI4.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAgLD.png

```
<Context.Consumer>
  {( test = { date, updateDate }) => (
    <ColumnContainer>
      <label>Date</label>
      <DatePicker
        name="date"
        type="date"
        onChange={updateDate}
        value={date}
      />
    </ColumnContainer>
  )}
</Context.Consumer>

<ColumnContainer>
  <Button onClick={this.DatePicker.updateDate} >Add</Button>
</ColumnContainer>
```

Comment: Ideally the date value is stored in a parent component of both elements. You pass the update event up to the parent and the parent passes the date value down to the datepicker. You don't normally pass data directly among peers, or sibling components.

Comment: The code you have provided is not enough to paint a clear picture of what you want...

Comment: @SakoBu i update, check the capture

Comment: @isherwood how I can ?

Comment: The official tutorial lays it out fairly well. I'd follow that model. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: @isherwood this is something for fast, then I will see tutorials later. but thanks

Comment: Reading through that in a few minutes will make your results not only fast, but good.

Comment: @isherwood  Thank you, later when I have time I do it and I'm guided by other examples